# Method for addind script in footer of Joomla (Using my plugin)

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a plugin for Joomla, which needs to add a javascript code in footer of the joomla site pages. Is there any method of adding such script to footer, without hacking the core files, as whoever installs the plugin, that script will get added.

Comment: I did research on Google, but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: I'd look at the methods that these extensions use to achieve that: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/12559 http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/12088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method to add a script to the footer. However you could make a plugin that gets the output, searches for an appropriately named tag, like footer and use str_replace to add in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For moving java scripts in footer need created new class in footer.php and write special function in document.php. Article on this subject - [Migrating Java scripts in the footer Joomla 2.5. Hack](http://tsyba.org/en/coding-laboratory/migrating-java-scripts-in-the-footer-joomla-2-5-hack.html)

Answer (score 0):

By now I think there's no option to load scripts on the bottom of the page.

But you can use these extensions achieve that:

1. [ScriptsDown](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/scriptsdown)
2. [JCH
   Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/jch-optimize)

Also i found one method. **I prefer not to hack the core code**, but that's the best I can come up with at the moment.

please check this link - [Javascript files includes in footer](https://github.com/rishiv3/joomla-adding-javascript-file-in-the-footer)

I Hope it will help others :)